# Make buddypress posts likes count show to all users

Tags: plugins, buddypress

Im using the buddypress likes plugin and I'm using a code to show the like count for posts on the index page of my site. The problem Im running into is the Like count only shows if you've liked the post and then it shows the total number. If you're logged out you won't see any like counts. How can I show the Like Counts to everyone? Here's how I call it inside the index page loop.

```
<?php if ( bp_like_is_liked( $id, 'blogpost' ) ) : ?>
    <?php 
      $liked_count = count( get_post_meta( $id, 'liked_count', true ) );
      if ( $liked_count ) echo 'Likes '. $liked_count . ''; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

I changed it so now all the liked show but for some reason all posts show atleast a like count of 1 even when they don't have any. Any idea why that is. Here's what I changed.

```
<?php 
      $liked_count = count( get_post_meta( $id, 'liked_count', true ) );
      if ( !$liked_count==0 ) echo 'Likes '. $liked_count . ''; ?>
```

Comment: I changed `if ( !$liked_count==0 )` to `if ( !$liked_count > 0 )` which didn't change anything. They I set it to > 1 and then it made all the counts disappear that were actually 1 and others that were set 0 and showing 1. So nothing solved yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `count()` function to determine `$liked_count`. This function is meant to determine the number of items in an array. But it appears that the value stored in the `liked_count` postmeta is not an array, but an integer count. When you do `count( $p )` where `$p` is an integer, you get `1` no matter what the integer is.

Try this instead:

```
$liked_count = (int) get_post_meta( $id, 'liked_count', true );
```

Comment: That oddly enough returns a 1 for any post that has been liked at least once.

Comment: What does it look like when you `var_dump( get_post_meta( $id, 'liked_count', true ) );` ?

Comment: This is what it shows for a post with two likes `array(2) { [1]=> string(10) "user_likes" [4]=> string(10) "user_likes" } Likes` ...this is what it shows for a post with 1 like `array(1) { [1]=> string(10) "user_likes" } Likes` ...and this is 0 liked `string(0) "" Likes`

Comment: Oh. Then `count()` should work.